# how to change (and keep) the color of a button on click

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I would like to toggle the color of a button upon a user click. Right now, when the user clicks the button momentarily changes color but then immediately changes back to the 1st color in milliseconds. I am using a .jsp file to communicate to a server on these button clicks which sends information to the server, and when the server communicates back it refreshed the page. Is this re-setting the style of the button when the page refreshes? I am using a class 'button' to define the style.

My question is: how can I indefinitely change the color of the button?

```
<form action="FirstServlet" method="get"> 
<div id="TVs"> 
  <%for (int i=1; i<=numTargets; i++) {         
    <button id="TV<%=i%>" name= "TV<%=i%>" class="button" onClick= "TVbuttonPressed('TV<%=i%>')">

...
    function TVbuttonPressed(id){       
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor  = 0xFFFF00;
}
```

Eventually I am planning to have the function be:

```
function TVbuttonPressed(id){       
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor  == A)
       document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor  = B

   else (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor  == B)
       document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor  = A
}
```

Can someone help explain? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just add a class on click. Have the class declare the new style.

Comment: `style.backgroundColor` will return different things in different browsers, and in most modern browsers it will return something like `rgba(23,143,255,1)`, so comparing against a hex color will almost always fail.

Comment: u could cache the color. and then set it accordingly. i also have a wild guess, like putting a href over the button width its width equal to the buttonwidth and then u will have a: visited{ background-color:red;}

Answer (score 0):

Place the return false in the called function

```
function TVbuttonPressed(id){       
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor  = 0xFFFF00;

return false;  --this will prevent the change of color while refreshing.
```

}

it will work

Comment: Thanks @Pavan-kumar.. I tried this and it was still unsuccessful. Button blinks yellow then returns to normal color. I originally thought this was because of a refresh problem..when I remove the action=FirstServlet.java attribute, the problem still exists which confuses me because the page doesn't have to talk to the server and come back to refresh anymore.   Does anyone know how I can set the backgroundColor from my Java servlet so when the .jsp page refreshes it sets the color based on info passed from the server? I have tried looking extensively for this, but no luck.