# Set the color of a button on http request from Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, button

I am trying to develop a webservice where one feature  would be to set the color of a button on a user click. Previously I tried to set this using JavaScript, but am not able to permanently keep the color change  [(see previous post here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749200/how-to-change-and-keep-the-color-of-a-button-on-click/20749343?noredirect=1#20749343). What I would like to do is have the user select multiple buttons, then submit information based on the buttons selected (like a checkbox, but using buttons to be touch-screen friendly).

How can send information from my Java Servlet to my .jsp file indicating the color of the button?

<---JAVA SERVLET --->

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
if (request.getParameter("TV1") != null){ 
        toggleButton(1, request);                       
    }

}

public void toggleButton(int targetNum, HttpServletRequest req){
    //button previously selected.. go to deselect..
    if (pressedOnce[targetNum] == true){ 
        pressedOnce[targetNum] = false; 
        req.setAttribute("buttonColor","yellow");
    }
    //button not selected previously.. go to select..
    else{
        targetsSelected[targetNum] = targetNum; //TV1 selected 
        pressedOnce[targetNum] = true;
        req.setAttribute("buttonColor","green");
    }
}
```

<--- JSP ---->

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .button {color:green;    
             background-color: <%= request.getAttribute("buttonColor") %>;
             font-size: 150%; 
             font-family: Arial Black;
             width:<%=(buttonWidth+"px")%>; 
             height:<%=(buttonHeight+"px")%>}
```

...

```
<form action="FirstServlet" method="get"> 
<div id="TVs">    
  <%for (int i=1; i<=numTargets; i++) {
 <button id="TV<%=i%>" name= "TV<%=i%>" class="button"> 
<%}%>
```

Is there a way to set the style class or background color in my JSP from the JavaServlet? When I try to setAttribute("buttonColor", "yellow"); nothing happens. I know I am missing something fundamental here.. but if someone could help me out I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the values you want on the user **session**, not the user **request**.

And don't use instance properties in your servlet (for example the **pressedOnce**);

So, try to add the variable **pressedOnce** to the user session. This way:

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("pressedOnceAttribute", pressedOnce);
```

Now this object is bounded to that specific user session.

Now, everytime the user hit the servlet, you will need to see if that user already has a session.

See here for more info:

http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/project5/session_tutorial.html